# Keep bounty remark after it is ended

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, bounty-remarks

Sometime I see bounties are set to gain the attention plus **adding extra features** to the question.

I cannot see the bounty remark after it is awarded or ended. So the answer may not be valid if the **extra feature** is added to the answer.

So IMHO the bounty remark(user comment on bounty) should be kept as it is the part of question.